# Unable to find my outlook addin on Android and IOS outlook app

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, office-store

Our manifest file for an Office 365 Outlook recently got approved and added to the office store.

When I try to look for our add-in under the Add-ins section on either Outlook for Android or Outlook for iOS, the add-in isn't visible.
Interestingly it shows up on these apps if added previously from Outlook for Web.

**Notes:**

- During submission, we tick marked both Android and iOS and supplied Apple Dev Id.
- The manifest file contains the MobileFormFactor tag.
- The minimum requirement set in manifest file is 1.5 (supported for Outlook for iOS / Android)

Appreciate any advise on what I might have missed.

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution

Comment: Can you share your add-in name? we can follow up with store team internally.

Comment: It's "Dealflow by Fundwave".

Comment: We checked and found that Dealflow did not pass the design review and we had shared the design review comments on 19th June. The suggested design changes have not been done. Can you please make the suggested changes to support mobile also?
There is no callout here- https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200001975?tab=Overview that it supports mobile. It would have got approved only for Desktop, OWA and Mac